# Conversion of PDF to XML using Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, data-science

I was given a work to convert PDF to XML. In XML, I have to display some values which are in PDF.
And I was asked to use Python-3 and Machine Learning to extract the values.

Any Suggestions or ideas on how to create an ML model to extract info from PFDs.

**Problem in Detail :**
if i have a pdf having values, for example :

emp id : 10000
name : raam

Then i have to extract the empid and name from PDF and display them to XML document.

**Note : The model should be able to process thousands of PDFs and convert them to XML docs.**

Thank U...

Comment: Hi - Theres is a lot you need to clarify - first off, are the PDF's scanned (images of documents) or are they text based? if text based, you need to start parsing your pdf, if you've been asked for an ML solution, I assume it has images. Here you first need to OCR (recognise characters) and ROI (regions of interest) in your document using something like opencv or pytesseract, and then using a pre-annotated dataset like FUNSD, train a system to identify questions and answers or similar entities inside your document.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API which can be used to convert PDF to Excel (.xlsx), XML or CSV: [PDFTables](https://pdftables.com/blog/pdf-to-excel-with-python). Let us know if this helps you.

Comment: «I was asked to use **Python-3 and Machine Learning** to extract the values.

Comment: Machine Learning is a broad term. What do you specifically mean by using ML to extract values from a PDF?